# What kind of verb is 'saw' in 'I saw him do X'

Tags: grammar, verbs

I'm just curious to know what kind of verb that is. I know that 'made' is a [causative verb](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-causative-verb-1689833) in the following sentence:

> I **made** him do X

But I don't think 'saw' is causative in the following sentence as it doesn't cause 'him' (is it the subject?) to do anything:

> I **saw** him do X

I couldn't find anything on Google. Can anyone give some insight?

Comment: As you might know, I don't know grammar, but I'm just curious.

Comment: Action verb, no? The transitive kind, I think.

Comment: It is a verb of **perception**. Other verbs in the same class are "feel", "hear", and "taste".

Comment: @Astralbee: Sure. A dictionary also says that 'make' is transitive, but here it's another kind of categorisation and is "causative" which I don't think can be answered by a dictionary. Also, as user178049 said in a comment, it's a "verb of perception" which I didn't find in any dictionary. So I don't think it can be answered by a dictionary. Which dictionary says it's "a verb of perception"? Can you provide a link?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I made him do it.
> You saw him do it.

It isn't quite natural to see the verb *to see* as a causative verb in its sentence above.  It's technically possible, maybe, at a stretch -- the verb does have a causative sense among the several senses that it carries.  However, the grammar of that sense is usually different.  If something needs to get done and I'm not going to handle it personally, I might ask you to *see to it* or *see that it gets done*.  That's different than this example.  It's more natural to take this example literally, using your eyes rather than your supervisory and managerial skills.

Sure, the two sentences above have different semantics.  This "made" is causative and this "saw" is perceptive.  I'm guessing that you're more interested in the similarity than the difference.  The two sentences do use the same grammar.

Subject, verb, direct object, object complement -- both sentences are [complexly transitive](https://www.google.com/search?q=complex+transitive+verb).  This is the [SVOC sentence pattern](https://www.google.com/search?q=svoc+sentence+pattern+examples).

The general pattern isn't limited to causation and perception.  I want you to understand that, because

> I want you to understand that.

is also SVOC.

Answer (score 1):

A *causative* verb is used to indicate that one person causes another person to do something for the first person. "Saw" (the past tense of *to see*) is **not** a causative verb as it cannot be used to *cause* someone else do something.

The causative verbs are: *let, make, have,* and *get*.

The verb *to see* is usually a *transitive verb* - one which must have an object. For example, in "I saw him", 'him' is the object. It can sometimes be an intransitive verb when referring to the *ability* of sight, for example, "I can see".

'*See*' also falls into the sub-category of "*perception verbs*" (to see, to hear, to feel, to smell, to taste). These are verbs of *involuntary perception*, so quite opposite to 'causitive'. For example, you might deliberately 'look' at something, but you cannot help but 'see' what is in front of your eyes.

Causative sentences and transitive sentences may be very similar, for example:

- Have the child wake up (causative)
- Wake the child up (transitive)

In both examples, the first person is asking someone else to wake a child. In the first example, the causative verb '*have*' is used and the verb 'wake' has no object; in the second example the verb 'wake' has an object - the child.